# How to correctly inject adalprovier in the config.js for angular js APP

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following piece of code

app.js

```
(function () {
    angular.module('inspinia', [
        'ui.router',                    // Routing
        'oc.lazyLoad',                  // ocLazyLoad
        'ui.bootstrap',                 // Ui Bootstrap
        'pascalprecht.translate',       // Angular Translate
        'ngIdle',                       // Idle timer
        'AdalAngular'                   //ADAL JS Angular
    ])
})();
```

and config.js

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider, IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider, adalProvider) {

    adalProvider.init(
       {
           instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
           tenant: 'mysaasapp.onmicrosoft.com',
           clientId: '33e037a7-b1aa-42ab-9693-6c22d01ca338',
           extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
           //cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
       },
       $httpProvider
       );

    // Configure Idle settings
    IdleProvider.idle(5); // in seconds
    IdleProvider.timeout(120); // in seconds

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboards/dashboard_1");

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        // Set to true if you want to see what and when is dynamically loaded
        debug: false
    });

    $stateProvider

        .state('dashboards', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/dashboards",
            templateUrl: "views/common/content.html",
        })
        .state('dashboards.dashboard_1', {
            url: "/dashboard_1",
            templateUrl: "views/dashboard_1.html",
            requireADLogin: true,
```

I get however this huge exception:

```
> Error: [$injector:modulerr]
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=inspinia&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.7%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3DadalProvider%0AT%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0AOb%2Fn.%24injector%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A307%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A308%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A64%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A293%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A425%0As%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A300%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A202%0AOb%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A435%0Asc%2Fd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350%0Asc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A153%0AJd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A16%3A483%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A249%3A412%0An.Callbacks%2Fj%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery-2.1.1.min.js%3A2%3A26855%0An.Callbacks%2Fk.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery-2.1.1.min.js%3A2%3A27673%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery-2.1.1.min.js%3A2%3A29465%0AI%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery-2.1.1.min.js%3A2%3A29656%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fapp.js%3A15%3A6%0A
> angular.min.js:6:415 Error: [$injector:modulerr]
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=inspinia&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.7%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3DadalProvider%0AT%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0AOb%2Fn.%24injector%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A307%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A308%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A64%0Ad%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A293%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A425%0As%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A300%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A202%0AOb%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A435%0Asc%2Fd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350%0Asc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A153%0AJd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A16%3A483%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A249%3A412%0An.Callbacks%2Fj%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery-2.1.1.min.js%3A2%3A26855%0An.Callbacks%2Fk.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery-2.1.1.min.js%3A2%3A27673%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery-2.1.1.min.js%3A2%3A29465%0AI%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fjquery%2Fjquery-2.1.1.min.js%3A2%3A29656%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A21425%2Fjs%2Fapp.js%3A15%3A6%0A
> angular.min.js:6:415
```

I nailed it down to this , adalProvider) in the config.js, if I remove it, it starts working again

My code is based on this: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-AngularJS-DotNet/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/app.js

With the difference that in that example they do the config on the same app.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AdalProvider` is not the correct name of `provider` it should be `adalAuthenticationServiceProvider`.

If you look at [**this line**](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-AngularJS-DotNet/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/app.js#L3) `AdalProvider` is used as reference for the dependency which has injected in array, As you're directly injecting the dependency in your function then that dependency would be `adalAuthenticationServiceProvider` instead of `adalProvider`.

**Code**

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider, IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider)
```

Comment: can you please explain in detail?

Comment: btw, the problem is still there, after replacing adalProvider with adalAuthenticationServiceProvider in config.js

Comment: maybe we ommited to include this piece of code, which is at the end of config.js,  http://screencast.com/t/92eEbDvAQQU

Comment: you should also replace there references in your app.js like `adalProvider.init` will replaced to `adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init`

Comment: @EstebanV you should have close it then..does it work after a change?

Comment: Hello, I changed it to this: and still doesnt work. http://screencast.com/t/goWT15jKVMpG btw, on my App.js I only have this: http://screencast.com/t/CUyksxn5X

Comment: btw, I think the error is different, httpProvider not defined. http://screencast.com/t/LtueQwMEM

Comment: I fixed it injecting the $httpprovider.!

Comment: @EstebanV let me check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80927/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-esteban-v).

Comment: @EstebanV but it seems like it already have injected here https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-AngularJS-DotNet/blob/master/TodoSPA/App/Scripts/app.js#L3 why you removed it in 1st place?

Comment: didnt remove it :( it wasnt there in the example code I downloaded.